# Is the following claim true?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\|\cdot\|)$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).

Let $S_1,S_2\in \mathcal{B}(F)$ such that $S_k(\text{ker}(M))\not\subset\text{ker}(M)$. Consider the follwoing subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
W
&=&\{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2;\;\exists(x_1,x_2)\in \text{ker}(M)\times \overline{\text{Im}(M)}\,;\|M^{1/2}x_2\|=1,\\
&&(\langle MS_1x_1,x_2\rangle+\langle MS_1x_2,x_2\rangle,\langle MS_2x_1,x_2\rangle+\langle MS_2x_2,x_2\rangle)=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

> I claim that $W=\mathbb{C}^2$. Is this claim true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, nothing you wrote prevents $S_1=S_2$, in which case $$W=\{(\lambda,\lambda):\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}.$$

**Example:** take $F=\mathbb C^2$,
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ S_1=S_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $$\ker M=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} \alpha\\0\end{bmatrix}:\ \alpha\in\mathbb C\right\},\ \ \ \text{Im}\,M=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\ \beta\end{bmatrix}:\ \beta\in\mathbb C \right\},
$$
and $S_j\ker M=\text{Im}\,M$, $j=1,2$.

If $x_2=\begin{bmatrix} \gamma\\ \delta\end{bmatrix}$, then $\|M^{1/2}x_2\|=|\delta|$, so we need $\delta=1$.  Now, with $x_1=\begin{bmatrix} r\\ s\end{bmatrix}$, 
$$
\langle MS_1x_1,x_2\rangle + \langle MS_1x_2,x_2\rangle
=r+\gamma.
$$
As $S_2=3S_1$, $$\langle MS_2x_1,x_2\rangle + \langle MS_2x_2,x_2\rangle=3\langle MS_1x_1,x_2\rangle + \langle MS_1x_2,x_2\rangle=3(r+\gamma).$$
Then
$$
W=\{(r+\gamma,3(r+\gamma)):\ r,\gamma\in\mathbb C\}=\{(\lambda,3\lambda):\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}\subsetneq\mathbb C^2. 
$$

Comment: $S_1$ is not necessary equal to $S_2$

Comment: But, if they are, $W$ is not $\mathbb C^2$. None of your hypotheses prevents this, so you'll hardly be able to prove that they are equal.

Comment: I try with so many examples and I get always $C^2$. Could you please give me in example in witch $W$ is different to $C^2$ when $Ker(M)$ is not an invariant subspace for $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: I have included some example. It doesn't make any difference what the example is, as long as $S_1=S_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the example but I don't understand why you take $S_1=S_2$.

Comment: Why not? You want me to take $S_2=2S_1$?

Comment: I want to prove that the claim is true or to find examples of $M$, $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $S_k(\text{ker}(M))\not\subset\text{ker}(M)$ but $W\neq\mathbb{C}^2.$

Comment: Since it seems important to you, I have modified the example to have $S_2\ne S_1$. In the example I gave you $S_k(\ker M)\not\subset\ker M$, and $W\ne\mathbb C^2$; that's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Yes Now I understand. Thank you